Parameters argument in Terraform "aws_glue_catalog_table" resource is not working
I am trying to create an AWS Athena Iceberg table using terraform. However key-value pairs added in the parameter argument of "aws_glue_catalog_table" resource block in not populated in the created Iceberg table.
Following is the terraform configuration I am using.
resource "aws_glue_catalog_database" "athena_fluent-inventory_db" {
  name = "fluent_inventory_database"
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "fluent_inventory_snapshot_iceberg_table" {
  name          = "fluent_inventory_snapshot_iceberg_table"
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.athena_fluent-inventory_db.name

  table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  open_table_format_input {
    iceberg_input {
      metadata_operation = "CREATE"
      version            = "2"
    }
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://${var.fluentInventorySnapshotIcebergStorageBucketName}/"
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
    columns {
      name = "id"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "status"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "quantity"
      type = "bigint"
    }
    columns {
      name = "group_reference"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "virtual_position_type"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "created_on"
      type = "timestamp"
    }
    columns {
      name = "updated_on"
      type = "timestamp"
    }
    columns {
      name = "product_reference"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "catalogue_id"
      type = "string"
    }
    columns {
      name = "external_reference"
      type = "string"
    }
  }

  parameters = {
    "vacuum_max_snapshot_age_seconds" = "2592000"
    "write_compression"               = "snappy"
    "format"                          = "parquet"
  }
}


When I apply above terraform script, the table is getting created. However If I give a "Show create Table query" on this table, it is missing the key-value pairs I added in the parameter argument.
Following is what the Create query table is returning
CREATE TABLE fluent_inventory_database.fluent_inventory_snapshot_iceberg_table (
  id string COMMENT '',
  status string COMMENT '',
  quantity bigint COMMENT '',
  group_reference string COMMENT '',
  virtual_position_type string COMMENT '',
  created_on timestamp COMMENT '',
  updated_on timestamp COMMENT '',
  product_reference string COMMENT '',
  catalogue_id string COMMENT '',
  external_reference string COMMENT '')
LOCATION 's3://fluent-inventory-snapshot-iceberg-storage-default'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'table_type'='iceberg'
);

